# D7: form input name array

Tags: 7, forms

need to build a form which has fields of type array.
php normally would:

```
<input name="MyArray[0]" />
<input name="MyArray[test]" />
<input name="MyArray[1]" />

$array = $_POST['MyArray'];
```

already tried the following but is not input as an array:

```
$form["MyArray[1]"] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
$form["MyArray[2]"] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
$form["MyArray[3]"] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
```

someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify them like this and set #tree to TRUE. Like this.

```
$form['MyArray']['#tree'] = TRUE;
$form["MyArray"][1] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
$form["MyArray"][2] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
$form["MyArray"][3] = _d7_taxonomy_term_select($node_type->name, 2, $default_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Drupals Form API to build forms.   You can't just create them like you did in your example

Resources:

- [Form API](http://drupal.org/node/37775)
- [Form API (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/204270) (methods are pretty much the same for drupal 7)
- [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7)

And probably the best one to get started

- [Form generation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7)